# How to parse json string in apex

Tags: json, salesforce, apex

i have json string like this downbelow

```
{"0":{"in":"mmm","loc":"1234"},"1":{"in":"mmm","loc":"1234"}}
```

Now i need to parse them as like

```
in | loc
---------
mmm| 1234
mmm| 1234
```

So far i did

```
public with sharing class Search 
{ 
    public String strTag {get;set;}
    public String strlocation {get;set;}
    public String result {get;set;}

    public PageReference find() {         

    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
    Http http = new Http();

    req.setEndpoint('http://test.3spire.net/index.php?in='+strTag+'&loc='+strlocation);
    req.setMethod('GET');

    //these parts of the POST you may want to customize
    req.setCompressed(false);
    req.setBody('key1=value1&key2=value2');
    req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');  

    try {
        res = http.send(req);       
    } catch(System.CalloutException e) {
        system.debug('Callout error: '+ e);
        result = ''+e;
    }

    Result results = (Result) JSON.deserialize(res.getBody(),ResultSet.class);

    result = res.getBody();
    system.debug(res.getBody());
        return null;
    }

    public class ResultSet{       
        public List<Result> resultSet;
    }

    public class Result
    {
        public String ins;
        public String loc;
    }
}
```

But its returns

**System.TypeException: Invalid conversion from runtime type Search.ResultSet to Search.Result**

How can i solved this problem

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling `JSON.deserialize(res.getBody(),ResultSet.class)`. The second parameter `ResultSet` is the Apex object type you want the result to be. But then you attempt to cast it to a type of `Result` instead.

Either do

`Result results = JSON.deserialize(res.getBody(), Result.class);`

or

```
ResultSet results = JSON.deserialize(res.getBody(), ResultSet.class);
```

In your case, based on the JSON it would seem you want the second option. However, your JSON doesn't quite match your ResultSet class either. Your JSON is a map, not a list. Also, there's a field mismatch between "in" and "ins". This JSON is what would match your ResultSet class:

```
{{"ins":"mmm","loc":"1234"},{"ins":"mmm","loc":"1234"}}
```